# How set font awesome Icon witha text using jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css, font-awesome

I used to set font awesome icon to a `div` using jquery but failed. I need to set font awesome icon before the given text "Web Frameworks" with some styles. This is jquery line.

```
$('#webTitle').html("Web Frameworks");
```

This is font awesome icon that I need to insert.

```
<i class="fa fa-bar-chart fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-right: 20px;"></i>
```

Can anyone suggest best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just include the `<i>` tag in [`.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/) function, here is a working snippet:

```js
$('#webTitle').html('<i class="fa fa-bar-chart fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-right: 20px;"></i>Web Frameworks');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="webTitle"></div>
```